# scraping data in dt dd tags with links inside them

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Actually I want to scrape data from a website "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/ani-technologies#/entity" where my data is present inside dt and dd tags and since bot are not allowed on the website. So I saved the page and applied beautifulsoup module on that saved page by this way,though I have mentioned actual url in the code

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(r"C:\Users\acer\Desktop\pythonbooks\tam.html").read())
```

---

```
import requests
ctr=1
file=requests.get("https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/ani-technologies#/entity")
soup = BeautifulSoup(file).read()
dl_data = soup.find_all("dd")
for dlitem in dl_data:
    print(ctr,dlitem.string)
    ctr+=1
```

> Actual Output:
>
> ```
> 0 3 Acquisitions
> 1 None
> 2 Bengaluru, Karnataka
> 3 Ola is a mobile app for cab booking in India.
> 4 None
> 5 None
> 6 olacab link
> 7 None
> 8 December 3, 2010
> 9 ANI Technologies Pvt Ltd, Olacabs.com, Ola Cabs, Olacabs
> 10 media@olacabs.com
> 11 None
> ```

Here at several places I got None due to the facts that there were hyperlinks to the contents.for e.g. on the page "https://www.crunchbase.com/organization/ani-technologies#/entity" the categories tab have 5 categories named :E-Commerce, Internet, Transportation, Apps and Mobile and each one is connected to a hyperlink so I cant get the text that I want i.e. these 5 categories.

> What I want as output as:
>
> ```
> 0 3 Acquisitions
> 1 (All that text (though not important to me))
> 2 Bengaluru, Karnataka
> 3 Ola is a mobile app for cab booking in India.
> 4 (all that text(though not important to me))
> ==>5 (E-Commerce, Internet, Transportation, Apps, Mobile)(Extremely important)
> 6 olacab link
> 7 (all that text(though not important to me))
> 8 December 3, 2010
> 9 ANI Technologies Pvt Ltd, Olacabs.com, Ola Cabs, Olacabs
> 10 media@olacabs.com
> 11 (all that text(though not important to me))
> ```

It will be most helpful if I can get dictionary something like this :

```
{"Headquarters":["Bengaluru,Karnataka"],
 "Description":["Ola is a mobile app for cab booking in India."],
 "Category": ["E-Commerce", "Internet", "Transportation", "Apps", "Mobile"]}
```

Comment: No,actually I have got None where the text was actually there but due to some nesting of tags(due to hyperlinks) i am not able to extract that text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Question**: ... I cant get the text that I want ... if I can get dictionary ...

Get `text/href` from all `<dd><a href=...>text</dd>`, to aggregate into a `dict`, for instance:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
os_dict = OrderedDict()

for div_class in ['definition-list-container', 'details definition-list']:
    divs = soup.find_all("div", class_=div_class)
    key = '?'
    for div in divs:
        for child in div.findChildren():
            if child.name == 'dt':
                key = child.text[:-1]
            if child.name == 'dd':
                if child.select('a[href]'):
                    a_list = child.find_all("a")
                    if key in ['Social:']:
                        os_dict[key] = [a['href'] for a in a_list]
                    elif len(a_list) == 1:
                        os_dict[key] = a_list[0].text
                    else:
                        os_dict[key] = [a.text for a in a_list]
                else:
                    os_dict[key] = child.text

for n, key in enumerate(os_dict, 1):
    print('{:>2}: {:>20}:\t{}'.format(n, key, os_dict[key]))
```

> **Outuput**:
>
> ```
>  1:          Acquisition:   3 Acquisitions
>  2:  Total Equity Fundin:   ['11 Rounds', '24 Investors']
>  3:         Headquarters:   Bengaluru, Karnataka
>  4:          Description:   Ola is a mobile app for cab booking in India.
>  5:             Founders:   ['Bhavish Aggarwal', 'Ankit Bhati']
>  6:           Categories:   ['E-Commerce', 'Internet', 'Transportation', 'Apps', 'Mobile']
>  7:              Website:   http://www.olacabs.com
>  8:              Social::   ['http://www.facebook.com/olacabs', 'http://twitter.com/olacabs', 'http://www.linkedin.com/company/olacabs-com']
>  9:              Founded:   December 3, 2010
> 10:              Aliases:   ANI Technologies Pvt Ltd, Olacabs.com, Ola Cabs, Olacabs
> 11:              Contact:   media@olacabs.com
> 12:            Employees:   8 in Crunchbase
> ```

---

> Beautiful Soup Documentation: [find-all](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)
>   Signature: find_all(name, attrs, recursive, string, limit, **kwargs)

```
dl_data = soup.find_all("dd")
for n, dlitem in enumerate(dl_data, 1):
    if dlitem.select('a[href]'):
        a_text = [a.text for a in dlitem.find_all("a")]
        print('{}: {}'.format(n, a_text))
    else:
        print('{}: {}'.format(n, dlitem.text))
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - bs4:4.6.0***